# How to set up Google DFP (DoubleClick for Publishers) for a site?

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console, google-adsense, google-dfp

I have a website and I have an AdSense account as well.

I have integrated AdSense and ads are also getting displayed (480 x 60). Somewhere I read that I can manage the ads that are being shown in my website (480 x 60) and filter out the ads on a CPM/CPC basis.

NOTE: I don't have any ads to be displayed on other's websites. I just want to show other's ads on my website.

Now, can I use Google DFP to manage the ads? I mean is Google DFP useful for me to filter the ads and get me more revenue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want show ads on your site other than Adsense Ads? If you are only showing adsense ads, DFP isn't much use to you.

If you have other ads to show as well, you can have them compete with Adsense ads.  DFP can be configured to show other ads unless adsense is likely to have a higher CPM/CPC.